# JavaScript: A dictionary of functions: Can a function reference functions from its dictionary?

Tags: javascript, function, dictionary, this

In the code below, when `somethingUseful.thisUsefulThing` is called from `setTimeout`, can it reference `somethingUseful.thatUsefulThing`?

```
var somethingUseful = {
  thisUsefulThing: function() {
    this.thatUsefulThing();
  },

  thatUsefulThing: function() {
    console.log("I am useful!");
  }
}

setTimeout(somethingUseful.thisUsefulThing, 1000);
```

Right now, I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'thatUsefulThing'
```

Comment: What do you mean "scope of global" vs "scope of the object"? Your code as written works.

Comment: Just keep in mind that when you do `object.method()`, the value of `this` in `method` becomes a reference to `object`. Makes no difference where or when the object and method were created. All that matters is *how* you call the method. Put that same method on a different object, call it from that object, and the value of `this` will refer to the new object. `var o = {thatUsefulThing:function() {console.log("I'm useful too!");}}; o.foo = somethingUseful.thisUsefulThing; o.foo(); // I'm useful too`

Comment: There, I edited it to directly reflect the error I'm encountering in a nutshell.

Comment: That's because you're sending the method to `setTimeout` by detaching it from the object. Remember, `this` is determined by how the method is called. When you do `object.method()`, the `method` can see that it is being called from `object` so `this` becomes `object`. If you detach it, as I showed in my comment above, its `this` will be based on how it was now being called. If it's not called from some object, it gets the default `window` object.

Comment: ...to keep them joined, pass an anonymous function that invokes the method from the object. `setTimeout(function() {somethingUseful.thisUsefulThing();}, 1000);`

Comment: @Synthead Please avoid the upvoted answer at all costs. It's a good example how not to write JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simply answer your question, YES, thisUsefulThing CAN access thatUsefulThing

But as your code currently runs, 'this' is not actually global, it is a reference to somethingUseful to all direct descendants itself.

When I am working with literal objects, I usually reference them by name rather than with 'this', so in your case I would replace 'this.thatUsefulThing()' with somethingUseful.thatUsefulThing()

Why? Because it works globally, anyway!

EDIT:

As plalx pointed out in his comment to my answer, best practices for implementing this class (with an example class member) would use functional classes / prototypes and look something like this:

```
function SomethingUseful () {
    this.member = 'I am a member';
}
SomethingUseful.prototype.thisUsefulThing = function () {
    this.thatUsefulThing();
}
SomethingUseful.prototype.thatUsefulThing = function () {
    console.log('I am useful, and ' + this.member);
}
usefulObject = new SomethingUseful();

usefulObject.thisUsefulThing(); // logs fine with access to this.member
setInterval(usefulObject.thisUsefulThing.bind(usefulObject), 1000); // has access to this.member through bind()
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, too ... especially when the code I posted actually worked, hahaha.  Take a second to look over my edited question, if you would.  And yes, JavaScript is a (much overdue) new one my list.

Comment: To solve your question I would still change 'this.thatUsefulThing()' to 'somethingUseful.thatUsefulThing()'

Answer (score 1):

Just bind the `this` value to `somethingUseful`.

```
setTimeout(somethingUseful.thisUsefulThing.bind(somethingUseful), 1000);
```

Comment: @i-live-in-a-storm-drain Actually I think it's quite the opposite. Relying on a variable name is quite inflexible, error-prone and far from being DRY.

Comment: Using `this` allows an object to be inheritable and instantiable/clonable. Therefore using `this` in general is a better design choice. Bind allows you to use `this` yet also allows you to set its value to the object you really mean if necessary.

Comment: @i-live-in-a-storm-drain In addition, using `this` avoid to create an unecessary closure over the variable. It also avoid unexpected results such as: `var o = { test: 'test', getTest: function () { o.test; } },
    o2 = o;

o = null;
o2.getTest();`

Comment: All very good points. I still would prefer not to have to bind all the time, which is why I emulate classes with
    function MyClass(){this.public=42; private=666;}; objMyClass = new MyClass();
It's funner.

Comment: That is, rather than using literal objects.

Comment: @i-live-in-a-storm-drain There's no difference, unless you inefficiently implement first-class functions with priviledged members (no use of the prototype), but that would be another bad practice.